# How do I make it so classes in the same namespace as a class have access to a variable but classes outside of a namespace don't in C#?

Tags: c#

```cs
namespace ExampleNamespaceOne {
    public class ExampleClassOne {
        public float Example = 0.5f;
    }
    public class ExampleClassTwo {
        // Has access to example.
    }
}

namespace ExampleNamespaceTwo {
    public class ExampleClassOne {
        // Doesn't have access to example.
    }
}
```

Take this code for example. I want the Example variable in the ExampleClassOne in the ExampleNamespaceOne to be accessible by any class in it's namespace. So I want ExampleClassTwo to be able to access it (Because it's in the same namespace) but I don't want ExampleClassOne in the ExampleNamespaceTwo to be able to access it (Because it's in a different namespace).

Comment: Are you thinking that namespaces are counterparts of _modules_ in other languages (I see you have a few posts about Swift)? And you want something internal to a module? _Assemblies_ are counterparts to modules, not namespaces, and the access modifier you want is `internal`.

Comment: This would be especially troubling because namespaces and assemblies are orthogonal - multiple assemblies can contain types within the same namespace, and an assembly can contain types in multiple assemblies. Do you really want that someone can create a new assembly and gain access to Example just by choosing to put a class in the `ExampleNamespaceOne` namespace?

Comment: To do that, you should make the `ExampleNamespaceOne`  and `ExampleNamespaceTwo`  are in the different assembly, then use `internal float Example = 0.5f;` to restrict the access scope only in the whole assembly of  `ExampleNamespaceOne`. Please refer: https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/csharp/csharp-access-modifiers-public-private-protected-internal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, however it is possible to define a variable/type/... with a visibilty that makes it "public" within the same assembly, but not accessible from any other assembly, maybe this could fit your purpose.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/internal

Answer (score 1):

You can't, namespaces are just a convenient tool to classify types and avoid name collisions.

In order to achieve more or less what you want you need to:

1. Make an assembly with `ExampleNameSpaceOne` namespace and the types contained within.
2. Make`ExampleClassOne.Example` `internal`

Now any type defined in any other assembly will not be able to see `Example`.

Of course `Example` will always be reachable through reflection, but you can't prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

You can pretty much do what you want, if you're happy to use nested types.

Check out this example:

```
public class ExampleClassOne
{
    private float Example = 0.5f;
    public class ExampleClassTwo
    {
        public ExampleClassTwo(ExampleClassOne one)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(one.Example); //access to `Example`!
        }
    }
}

public class ExampleClassThree
{
    public ExampleClassThree(ExampleClassOne one)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(one.Example); //No access to `Example`!
    }
}
```

`ExampleClassTwo` has access to `ExampleClassOne`'s private variables because it is nested within it.

`ExampleClassThree` does not have access.

You can use it like this:

```
var eco = new ExampleClassOne();
var ect = new ExampleClassOne.ExampleClassTwo(eco);
```

Now, this can be a bit cumbersome to deal with nested types, so a common pattern to give you this functionality is to implement it like this:

```
public class ExampleClassOne
{
    private float Example = 0.5f;
    public class ExampleClassTwoImpl : ExampleClassTwo
    {
        internal ExampleClassTwoImpl(ExampleClassOne one)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(one.Example); //access to `Example`!
        }
    }
}

public class ExampleClassTwo
{
    public static ExampleClassTwo Create(ExampleClassOne one)
        => new ExampleClassOne.ExampleClassTwoImpl(one);

    internal ExampleClassTwo() { }
}
```

In this pattern you use it like this:

```
var eco = new ExampleClassOne();
var ect = ExampleClassTwo.Create(eco);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use internal modifier:

```
    namespace ExampleNamespaceOne {
        public class ExampleClassOne
    {
        internal float Example = 0.5f;
    }
    public class ExampleClassTwo
    {
        public ExampleClassTwo()
        {
            ExampleClassOne obcts = new ExampleClassOne();
            obcts.Example = 1.0f;
        }

        // Has access to example.
    }
    }

    namespace ExampleNamespaceTwo 
    {
        public ExampleClassOne()
            {
                Practice.ExampleClassOne obcts = new Practice.ExampleClassOne();
\\ Doesn't have access to example.
                obcts.Example = 1.0f;
            }

    }
```

For more info refer - https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/puranindia/what-are-access-modifiers-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: You've mostly got the right idea, but your code doesn't compile. Also you can change `internal float Example = 0.5f;` to `private float Example = 0.5f;`.

Comment: code is just sample .it is not compilable. Private variable will not be accessible outside the class within same namespace .

Comment: Please make it compilable. In the vast majority of cases, I only post working code, not just compilable. I test almost everything I post.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I thought you had nested classes too. Yep. `private` won't work for you.

Comment: @Enigmativity seems like you are expert...still seems you are looking for a ready to eat solution...i just proposed a solution as idea as pseudo code..if anyone wants to use this logic he has to made changes according to their own scenario

Comment: And that's not the best approach on this site. Please pay attention to advice given by users with high rep points.

Comment: @Enigmativity you might need ready to use but i believe in solution should be logical and pseudo code is enough to describe the intention.

Comment: No, it is not logical and it is not enough. Please provide working code.